# Is there a way to keep the LCD on a D3500 active while using Snapbridge?

Tags: nikon, snapbridge

I have looked around and found out that as of now, the D3500 has limited use with the Snapbridge app.  I understand that the App will not show me what my camera is seeing and is mostly just there to push the button to take the picture.  (I think that is a pretty lame extent of the app as do most others I have seen)

So my question has to do with the camera itself.  While using Snapbridge, the camera screen will also go black and will force you to use the view finder.  Is there a way to continue to use the camera screen while using Snapbridge as the basic remote?

Comment: Running Snapbridge **and** the rear screen will kill your battery life. Any wireless communication system on a camera is a balance. The more expensive the camera, the better-equipped it will be for wireless tethering. You have the entry-level camera, your options are the most limited. If all you want Snapbridge for is to use as a remote, you'd be better off in all respects just buying a wired remote [10 bucks on eBay] & an extension cable.

Comment: From what I've read, the D3500 doesn't allow for wireless remotes, would a wired one work? are there wired remotes?  As you might see, I am completely new at this.  I had hoped that snapbridge would let me see the screen but I found out that it doesn't after I bought the camera.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad. Google suggests the older 3300 had a wired remote option, gone on the 3500. It seems Bluetooth may be the only viable option. Never tried it as my D5500 has wifi, not BT. Lot of chat on https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/4360125